How can I upgrade my raspberry pi os without deleting files
Is there a way to upgrade to/install bookworm on my raspberry pi 4b without deleting files? I saw the webpage on the raspberry pi website however I would prefer to not have to download it "manually" onto the SD card by placing it into my computer then downloading the operating system onto the SD card. Is there a way to download it like you would download a new version of windows or is there a way to do it through the command prompt? I am currently on buster and would like to upgrade to bookworm.

"... without deleting files?" Well... of course! You simply install 'bookworm' on a new/different SD card! As far as the rest of your question, sorry - but I cannot guess what you mean by "manually", or what you're talking about with your Windows comparison... I'd suggest you edit your question to make it clear.

ok. What I mean by not lose files is keep the projects I have been working on on the raspberry pi.

You back up your files so you can copy them into the new install.  If you currently don't back up your project files, the answer to "The filesystem on my SD card is corrupt, how can I rescue my project files?" is "Maybe you cannot".

This may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6u7YaIUaNxI

Thank you! That showed me how I can do it. Not sure if I can mark a comment as an answer but that fixed my problem.

You can NOT "upgrade" ANY Raspberry Pi OS version to Bookworm.
A fresh install is required.
